# Javascript inputfile contact form

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

i am struggling with importing the following JS code

```
'use strict';

;( function ( document, window, index )
{
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
{
    var label    = input.nextElementSibling,
        labelVal = label.innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
    {
        var fileName = '';
        if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
            fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
        else
            fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

        if( fileName )
            label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
        else
            label.innerHTML = labelVal;
    });

    // Firefox bug fix
    input.addEventListener( 'focus', function(){ input.classList.add( 'has-focus' ); });
    input.addEventListener( 'blur', function(){ input.classList.remove( 'has-focus' ); });
});
}( document, window, 0 ));
```

On this website: https://pimarketing.flywheelsites.com/careers/

The error i get in the debugger is: TypeError: label is null.

I guess something goes wrong with input.nextElementSibling. It should show the inputfile name but it doesn't. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Why can't you use the class for the input and get the value of the it ?

Comment: — Could you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Make sure that you have proper value in 'input' and also from 'input.nextElementSibling', as the error is due to null value for 'label'.

Comment: In collection returned by `querySelectorAll, second element is `<input type="file" name="your-resume" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file inputfile inputfile-1" id="file-1" aria-invalid="false">` which does not have `nextElementSibling` hence you are finding this error..

Comment: tried selecting it by id & class. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think null error mean it did no find that element which mean it is better to check if that element exist or not first than do rest of thing after. Please Try following code and let me know if it works for you.

```
  'use strict';
  ( function ( document, window, index )
  {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
  Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
  {
    var label    = input.nextElementSibling;
     if(label){    //checking if label exist or not
       var labelVal = label.innerHTML;

     input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
     {
         var fileName = '';
         if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
        fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
       else
        fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

    if( fileName )
        label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
    else
        label.innerHTML = labelVal;
   });
}
    // Firefox bug fix
    input.addEventListener( 'focus', function(){ input.classList.add( 'has-focus' ); });
    input.addEventListener( 'blur', function(){ input.classList.remove( 'has-focus' ); });
});
}( document, window, 0 ));
```

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out! It seems that it indeed couldnt find the element. I made the querySelector more specific and changed the label in HTML label for="file-0">

```
'use strict';

;( function ( document, window, index )
{
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#file-0');
Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
{
    var label    = input.nextElementSibling;
    if (!label) {
    return;
    }
    var labelVal = label.innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
    {
        var fileName = '';
        if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
            fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) ||            '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
        else
            fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

        if( fileName )
            label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
        else
            label.innerHTML = labelVal;
    });

    // Firefox bug fix
    input.addEventListener( 'focus', function(){ input.classList.add(     'has-focus' ); });
    input.addEventListener( 'blur', function(){ input.classList.remove( 'has-focus' ); });
});
}( document, window, 0 ));
```